# Android: how to get textview position from table

Tags: android, xml-parsing

In list view the position of particular row can easily be determined through array adapter and then by using onlistitemclick method we can have that value in toast message

but how can we get position or id of any particular text view(when it is clicked) from table view  where table rows are generating dynamically through xml parser..
where column names are id, name and class.
id is auto incremented..
pls suggest.

the code is

try {

```
        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();


        URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://ip-address/test/player.xml");


        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }


    DataList dataList = XMLHandler.DataList;


    name = new TextView[dataList.getName().size()];
    class = new TextView[dataList.getName().size()];

    /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
    for (int i = 0; i < DataList.getName().size(); i++) {

         TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
         tr.setId(100+i);
         tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

         // Create a TextView to house the name of the province
         name[i]= new TextView(this);
         name[i].setId(200+i);
         name[i].setText(dataList.getName().get(i));
         name[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
         name[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         tr.addView(name[i]);

         class[i] = new TextView(this);
         class[i].setId(i);
         class[i].setText(dataList.getClass().get(i));
         class[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
         class[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         tr.addView(class[i]);


        t1.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke ViewGroup method:

```
public int indexOfChild (View child)
```

on TableLayout, where child is TableRow. TableRow should be accesible through

```
public final ViewParent getParent ()
```

of View inside TableRow.

```
TableRow tableRow = (TableRow)mTextView.getParent();    

int index = -1;

if(parent != null){
    index = mTable.indexOfChild(tableRow);
}

if(index < 0){
    throw new IllegalStateException("TextView not found");
}
```

Hope that help, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: basically view group is not exactly clear to me.. so im not getting how to implement this with parsing.but still im trying.studying documentations and examples..

Comment: TableLayout is ViewGroup therefore has indexOfChild method.

Comment: finally its running n m getting id

Comment: simply i did is on click view i took text of that particular text view by jst getText.toString.now on clicking on id im getting it... thanx dziobas for ur advice that was also very helpful bz i learned new that i nvr thought b4 and alternate method..

Comment: I'm glad that have helped. Consider voting in your question.

Comment: For me that only returns the visible position of the view (because of recycling), not the overall position inside the table